# Sort Dictionary by top 10 values, also if a value is double then it should put them on the same place from 1-10

Tags: python, sorteddictionary

The function I made is the following:

```
r = 0
n = 10
checklist = []
for key, value in sorted(contribution.items(), key = lambda kv: kv[1], reverse = True):
    if value in checklist:
        print(str(r) + "\t" + key + "\t" + str(value))

    if value not in checklist:
        checklist.append(value)
        r = r + 1
        if not r > n:
            print(str(r) + "\t" + key + "\t" + str(value))
```

Now I need to add, that if there is are values which are the same that then it should put them in the same place.

Example:

my dict: 56, 19, 13, 56

1) 13

2) 19

3) 56 and 56

Comment: What should happen if there are 2 at #1, would the next entry be #2 (considering values) or #3 (considering ranks)?

Comment: @Edoardo Facchinelli next entry should be #2 considering the values

Comment: This should give you the 10 first unique values in ascending order (based on your sample output):
 sorted(list(set(contribution)))[:10]
 from there you could iterate the dict counting those keys that match.